# How to populate fact table with Surrogate keys from dimensions?

Tags: etl, ssis-2012, fact-table, surrogate-key

Could someone please help me understand how to populate the fact table with Surrogate keys from dimensions using SSIS?
I load my dimension tables and assign for each a surrogate key. I want to add these surrogate keys to my fact table but I don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You just join your fact source record to the relevant dimension tables and get the surrogate keys, which you then insert into your fact table